# Custom fields on comments?

Tags: ee2, templates, comment-form

Is there a way to add custom fields to content comments?

For example, I would like to add a date input field and a subject field.

Alternatively could this be accomplished with the Solspace plugin "Freeform Pro 4.0.8"?

Comment: For clarity, you want people to be able to modified the  enter date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no native way to add additional fields to the EE Comment module, no.

Freeform could work. You would have to have a [hidden field](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtype/#hidden) that stored the `entry_id` of the entry being commented on, so that you could then use `search:comment_entry_id="{entry_id}"` when listing the comments with the [Freeform Entries](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/#search_field_name) tag.

(Note that you'd likely have to either embed your "comments" Freeform Entries loop and pass the `entry_id` via an [embed variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template), or grab the `entry_id` from the URL - `{segment_3}` for example - in order to avoid variable collisions with the Channel Entries tag.)

Comment: Can freeform entries be sorted by the value of a field?

Comment: [Yup.](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/#orderby)

Comment: Nice! and would there be a way to automatically delete the comments that are associated with a product when said product is deleted?

Comment: With a custom extension, yes. You would use the [delete_entries_loop hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_edit/index.html#delete-entries-loop), and then delete the Freeform entries directly from the database which had the `comment_entry_id` (or whatever you call your field) which matched the value of the `$entry_id` passed by the hook.

Comment: Ah the other thing was moderation, is there a way to add moderation to comments that are posted using FreeForm?

Comment: Sure, you could set all new entries to have a custom status (or just "closed"), then even add a link directly to the Freeform Entries screen in the admin notification email, instructing the admin to "open" the entry if it's valid.

Comment: If you're using this approach for comments on channel entries, I'm guessing you lose the option for users to subscribe to additional comments?

Answer (score 5):

I would say the easiest thing to do would be to repurpose use of one of the existing fields, unless you are already using all of them. Comments can capture: name, email, url, location, and comment. I'm excluding creation and edit dates, as well as entry_id, ip_address, etc.

For example, if you are not using 'location' then use it and re-label it 'subject'.

Of course a number of sites, bypass EE's built in commenting system and use Disqus or Facebook.

Comment: I didn't want to make this part of my solution, but thought it would be good idea to bring up, that most sites, really have no need to offer subjects for comments. In fact, if you want more comments, subject is more of a deterrent than an aid. That said, if you want less comments with more focus, there maybe research that suggests adding a subject/title will aid in that, but I can't say if its true or not.

Comment: When it comes to a blog I couldn't agree more when it comes to the subject field. But in this case my client wants to use the comments as a review mechanism. The date is for the date purchased, and the subject is just the title of the review. In fact perhaps called "Review Title" instead of "Subject" as that makes more sense.

Comment: In that case, you should look at the [Rating module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/rating/). It offers star ratings, plus comments/reviews and custom fields for those comments/reviews.

Comment: @DerekHogue I agree that would be idea, but in this scenario if FreeForm can accomplish this it will be better because it will be cheaper. FreeForm could be used for a number of other purposes as well anyway, so if it can fit the reviews as well then that is a bonus!

Comment: I was thinking the only place I've seen subjects used for comments successfully is in reviews. In this case, I agree with @DerekHogue Solspace's Rating module is excellent. Yes, you can capture the data in FreeForm, but the Rating interface, allows you to rapidly see which items are doing well or bad, see all the ratings for a particular product, post, publication, average out ratings by reviewers, export ratings to a spreadsheet, and other things that I find beneficial. Plus, it's cheaper than FreeForm, though admittedly, you already have FreeForm.

Answer (score 4):

I would check out the [Rating Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/rating/) which offers "custom fields" for comments/reviews.

Edited to note: There is also [DevDemon's Channel Ratings](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_ratings/) which might also be worth looking into.

Each one offers different capabilities and one might fit your needs better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a custom extension. Here's the hooks you'll need:

- Create new database cols in exp_comments when you install the extension
- Add additional fields to the database insert array using the [insert_comment_insert_array](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/comment/index.html#insert-comment-insert-array) hook
- Then when comments are rendered use the [comment_entries_tagdata](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/comment/index.html#comment-entries-tagdata) hook to replace tags for the new comment fields.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed an add-on called [Custom Comment Fields](http://www.intoeetive.com/index.php/comments/custom-comment-fields-comment-uploads-in-ee2) that allows custom fields to be submitted with comments (handles text inputs, textares and attachments via Safecracker File field). Datepicker not supported yet, but is in plans.